# Why this weird difference when overriding a method in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Would like to check if anybody has a clue why would the first method cause a different effect than the second one? The first one makes what is called "Track" becomes 50 tall, but the second one doesn't change anything!

1)

```
public override CGRect TrackRectForBounds (CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds)
{
    base.TrackRectForBounds (new CGRect (forBounds.X, forBounds.Y, forBounds.Width, 50));
    return forBounds;
}
```

2)

```
public override CGRect TrackRectForBounds (CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds)
{
    return base.TrackRectForBounds (new CGRect (forBounds.X, forBounds.Y, forBounds.Width, 50));
}
```

Comment: They are indeed different.add code for base.TrackRectForBounds

Comment: You are not returning the object in second case its refrence only. whereas In first case you're letting the change happen and then returning the obect.

Comment: That would entirely depend on what `TrackRectForBounds` on your base class is defined to return. I can find a few references to such a method on iOS, but you don't typically write C# code for iOS. Maybe [edit] and add a tag if you're using some framework above and beyond just .NET.

Comment: Because 1 returns whatever you input and 2 returns whatever the base returns. In case of 1: as long as the base doesn't modify the input (by reference) you will get whatever you input. In case of 2: whatever base decides to do with input (even completely ignore it), you'll get whatever base wants to return.

Comment: We'll need to see the source code of the base method that you are overriding

Comment: They don't do anything different. The only difference I can imagine is what your calling code does with the returned value (as they return different values)

Comment: @musefan 'They don't do anything different.' Yes they do. They are substantially and utterly different. Let's assume for a second that base always will return `null`, regardless of input. Now look at 1) and 2) again. 1 Will return whatever you passed into it, 2 will always return `null`.

Comment: @RobIII: There are no references to modify, the base method gets a new object so wont change any references

Comment: @RobIII: return value means nothing to what `TrackRectForBounds` actually does. It will do the exact same processing in both instances. Yes, the functions return different values, but only the calling code can result in that causing different things to happen, and we can't see the calling code

Comment: Oh, crap, I totally overlooked the `new CGRect...`; however: by reference or not, the rest still stands. 1 will return exactly what you put in, 2 will return whatever base decides to return.

Comment: I'm guessing that the second one returns a reference to input object "new CGRect (forBounds.X, forBounds.Y, forBounds.Width, 50)"

Comment: @RobIII: I am not denying they return different results, but in the context of the code provided, there is nothing to make us believe anything is different. We need to see the code that calls this function, and see how it uses the result. For all we know nothing even uses the result and the problem is somewhere completely different

Comment: Do not provide a link to download your full code, include the relevant code directly in the question (not all the code). Basically we need to see the code that calls this method, and how it uses the returned value. But generally you should be able to debug this yourself easily

Answer (score 3):

The code does not show what the caller method does with the return value of the method `TrackRectForBounds()`.

But I suppose anything is done with the returned `GCRect` - and there's the difference: Method 1 does return the argument `forBounds` directly while Method 2 returns the values returned from `base.TrackRectForBounds()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do :

```
public override CGRect TrackRectForBounds(CoreGraphics.CGRect forBounds) 
{ 
    var baseReturnObj = base.TrackRectForBounds(new CGRect(forBounds.X, forBounds.Y, forBounds.Width, 50));
    return forBounds; 
}
```

And compare the objects of `forBounds` and `baseReturnObj` it should be obvious as to what is going on.